# Popup Window shows at the center of the screen and outside of the context

Tags: android, popup, window, screen, center

What I want is... there's a floating icon (always on top of other apps). Tapping it wil show a popup window which is on the center of the screen. I have tried the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063667/show-a-popupwindow-centralized) but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after wrestling with it, I found a way to do this. It's kinda tricky LOL.

```
    public void createWindow() {
    //initialize the popup window
    // blah blah blah and right before you're about to show it, create
    // a framelayout like the one below. And use windowmanager to addView 
    // (just like the way we create a floating icon on top of other apps)
    framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutparameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            width, height, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    parameters.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    manager.addView(framelayout, layoutparameters);
    framelayout.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pop.showAtLocation(framelayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    });
    }
```

Not done yet, my friends! Don't forget this in the method createWindow().

```
    pop.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        manager.removeView(framelayout);
                        framelayout = null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }, 500);
```

You can leave the handler. I use it because my popup window uses animation to dismiss (and yes my animation duration is 500 mili). Done!

Answer (score 1):

After tying so many functions got the expected result. Instead of using ShowAtLocation() use showAsDropDown(). Define Anchor point and width and height. If your min sdk is more than 16 then you can use gravity as fourth parameter.

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(mcontext.findViewById(R.id.ap1), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```