# Create popup at the middle of the screen

Tags: android

I am trying to create a popup when clicking on `ListView` image with the same image just enlarged, this code works fine to me but I tried to position the `View` "vv" at the middle of the screen but the popup is still at (0,0)..

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!popu) {
                    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
                    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                            popupView,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    TextView txt = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.texttt);
                    ImageButton img = (ImageButton) popupView.findViewById(R.id.imgg);
                    txt.setText(imageId[position]);
                    img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
                    View vv = new View(context);
                    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point size = new Point();
                    display.getSize(size);
                    int width = size.x;
                    int height = size.y;
                    vv.setX(width / 4);
                    vv.setY(height / 4);
                    img.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                            popu = false;
                        }
                    });
                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(vv, 50, -30);
                    popu = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

I am not on an activity, it is my `customadapter` class..

**EDIT:**
Fixed, see Yasin Kaçmaz answer.

Comment: Did you see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063667/show-a-popupwindow-centralized

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz Nope, Thanks for referring me there ! :)

Comment: no problem , if you fix your problem , notice there !