# ListPopupWindow wrong horizontal positioning

Tags: android, popup

[image]

As we see above am using ListPopupWindow to show a popup list that display 3 items and am initializing it using the below code:

```
    mPopupAdapter = new PopupWindowAdapter(LauncherActivity.this, microapps);
    mPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(LauncherActivity.this);
    mPopupWindow.setAdapter(mPopupAdapter);
    mPopupWindow.setAnchorView(mMicroAppBtn);
    mPopupWindow.setWidth(ListPopupWindow.MATCH_PARENT);
    mPopupWindow.setVerticalOffset(-60);
    mPopupWindow.setModal(true);
```

mMicroAppBtn is the big red button in the tab bar below.

On most devices ListPopupWindow is looking fine(not as above) in other words it is starting from the left of the screen not from it's center as above, which is what i want.

But on some devices it is showing like the image above, i tried several things but none worked for me.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063667/show-a-popupwindow-centralized

Comment: Am using ListPopupWindow no PopupWindow the solution in the link is not applicable, i mean there is no `showAtLocation()` method for ListPopupWindow

Comment: @MohammadHaidar Hi were you able to resolve the issue

Comment: @MRamzan i don't really remember but can you try adding         mPopupWindow.setPromptPosition(ListPopupWindow.POSITION_PROMPT_ABOVE);
 and removing     mPopupWindow.setVerticalOffset(-60);

Comment: I really appreciate your response. I do not know if it is a bug but setting verticle offset below -450 started working. After tweaking a little,  at -350 I got the desired position for it.