# showAsDropDown Gravity parameter not working

Tags: android, gravity, android-popupwindow

I am trying to center horizontally a `PopUpWindow` on the anchored view, but the `Gravity.CENTER` parameter is being ignored.

This is the method I am using:

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView, 0, 0, Gravity.CENTER);
```

No matter what CENTER gravity value I enter (also TOP or BOTTOM don't work), the pop-up always displays at the same place: the anchor's top left corner, unless I use the START or END values.

The documentation and javaDoc does not list any restriction on the values that it accepts, so I assume that it also accepts any of the CENTER, TOP and BOTTOM values: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow#showAsDropDown(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int)

I also tested this with anchor views that are smaller, equal and larger than the pop-up window and the pop-up window is set to not fill the screen width, as intended.

It appears that this method does nothing different from the equivalent method that does not take the gravity parameter

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView, 0, 0);
```

Is this a bug or is this not how it is suppose to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `PopupWindow.showAsDropDown()`, it seems that is working as intended, tracing through its source, you can eventually see that the gravity parameter is only meant for **horizontal** values.

Tracking the value of `gravity` from [PopupWindow.showAsDropDown()](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/PopupWindow.java#1263) to [PopupWindow.findDropDownPosition()](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/PopupWindow.java#findDropDownPosition), we can already see the hint `@param gravity horizontal gravity specifying popup alignment`

Then a step deeper to [Gravity.getAbsoluteGravity()](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/Gravity.java#412) also hints at the same thing `@param gravity The gravity to convert to absolute (horizontal) values.`

But I believe what you are looking to achieve is at [Show a PopupWindow centralized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063667/show-a-popupwindow-centralized), which uses `PopupWindow.showAtLocation()`

[PopupWindow.showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: `tracing through its source` Kind of defeats the purpose of having a javaDoc and a public documentation if we have to scan the entire stack of the source code to find this kind of information. Nevertheless it confirms my observations, so I appreciate the help.
I do not want to use the method you suggested because it will no longer follow the anchored view, it is the only reason why I am not using that option.

Comment: you're right, sometimes the docs are missing keywords that would make a world of difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but if you want to center the pop up window with showAsDropDown(), you can do this:

```
target.post(() -> {
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor, (anchor.getWidth() / 2), yOffset, Gravity.CENTER);
    });
```

It is inside target.post() to ensure that the anchor is drawn when we call getWidth(), otherwise it returns 0.

Answer (score -1):

What I'm doing is:

```
fun showPopupWindow(popupWindow : PopupWindow){
    popupWindow.width = 200
    popupWindow.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor, -(popupWindow.width - anchor.width)/2, 0,  Gravity.CENTER)
}
```

Make sure popupWindow.width and anchor.width are not 0, -1 or -2